# How to upgrade package one by one using apt-get with bash script?

Tags: apt, bash, upgrade, scripts

bash script that can upgrade pkg one by one. 
i think we can create a txt file that contain all upgrade able pkg and we can call every single line in terminal.

---

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo apt update`; `apt list --upgradable`; then `sudo apt upgrade` -- why do you need to do it one by one?

Comment: -1 Classic [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). In comments below, OP states that the *real* problem is flaky internet. There are simpler solutions than scripting one-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to give a try to

```
#!/bin/bash
while read package
do
apt install ${package} -y
done < requirement.txt
```

You might want to run the script.sh as root
If you want to only upgrade if it exists, and don't want to install it if it doesnt, add `--only-upgrade` (`apt install --only-upgrade ${package} -y`)

Comment: Every time when i try apt upgrade it start upgrading all pkgs and if internet issue occurs then it restart download form starting. That's why i want this script.  thanx alot.

Comment: @Rushikesh You can `sudo dpkg --configure -a` before running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again in that case. It might take a while tho, depending if its your computer or your internet connexion which is more reliable

Answer (score 1):

I have an ubuntu post installer script that I use at every clean installation of ubuntu. I wrote something near to your request, because it can be used to customize the output in the terminal. The script is:

```
  echo "Reading package list..."
  apt-get update -y >/dev/null 2>&1
  PKG_LIST="$(apt list -u | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $1}' | awk NR\>1)"
  for PKG_NAME in $PKG_LIST;
  do
    echo "$PKG_NAME is ready for update..."
    if apt-get install "$PKG_NAME" -y >/dev/null 2>&1;
    then
      echo "$PKG_NAME updated"
    else
      echo "WARNING: $PKG_NAME cannot be updated"
    fi
  done
```

the sequence is:

1. apt-update with no output on terminal (if you want it, you can remove the part after the -y parameter)
2. if there are package to update, they are written in a variable. This variable is built through an awk command that at first get only data befire the / character and then removes the first line of the data block (it's useless)
3. the variable is analyzed in a for-loop item by item and for every item the apt install is run.

With this code you don't need to put the upgradable packages in a text file, they are retrieved at "run-time"

If you want to read from file, modifications are easy:

```bsh
echo "Building list.txt"
PKG_LIST="$(apt list -u | awk 'BEGIN {FS="/"} {print $1}' | awk NR\>1)"
echo "${PKG_LIST}" > list.txt

echo "Reading package list..."
while read PKG_NAME;
 do
 echo "$PKG_NAME is ready for update..."
 if apt-get install "$PKG_NAME" -y >/dev/null 2>&1;
   then
     echo "$PKG_NAME updated"
   else
     echo "WARNING: $PKG_NAME cannot be updated"
 fi
 done < list.txt
```

Comment: approved the modifications suggested by B. du Garay

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` allows you to read packages from a file:

```
$ xargs -a package.txt -n 1 apt -y install
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line Command ( in sudo su ):

```
apt list -u -q 2>/dev/null | grep "/" | cut -d/ -f1 | xargs  -n 1 apt -y install
```

Comment: To make your answer useful please [edit] it to explain the details of your command.